# Why is my React function being declared but not read?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a basic React project and I thought I was doing everything right until I tried to import my generalInput file into my App file. I am being told that my generalInput is being declared but never read. I even put my code into  AI to see if I could get help but it was confused as well.

Here is the code:

```
import generalInput from "./generalInput";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <generalInput name="John" />
    </>
  );}
```

```js
export default function generalInput(name) {
  return (
    <>
      <label>{name}</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and basic thing is that when you create a component the first letter of its name should be capital

```
import GeneralInput from "./generalInput";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GeneralInput name="John" />
    </>
  );}
```

here is your updated component

```
export default function GeneralInput(name) {
  return (
    <>
      <label>{name}</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Hope this will fix your issue

Answer (score -1):

In React the first letter of a Component name usually needs to be capitalized.

So try this:

```
export default function GeneralInput(name) {
      return (
        <>
          <label>{name}</label>
          <input type="text" />
        </>
      );
    }
```

```
    import GeneralInput from "./GeneralInput";
    import "./styles.css";

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <GeneralInput name="John" />
        </>
      );}
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you need to reread React docs or `?X` compilers `jsx`, `tsx` never accept a component whose first character is number or lowercase please capitalize first letter like like this otherwise it will be treated as regular html tag

```
import GeneralInput from "./generalInput";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GeneralInput name="John" />
    </>
  );
}
```